# Does Server Location matter for SEO if you have a CDN?

Tags: seo, ranking, webserver, cdn

I'm looking into specialised hosting for WP, one provider has three different server locations but none in the UK.
However, they have over 30 CDN locations.

My question is, if I decide to put my site on a server outside of the UK.
Will this affect the sites SEO positioning, even though there is a CDN in place within the UK?

Comment: Only in as much as it effects site speed. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the previous comment. Technically for locale-specific sites like .co.uk Google would prefer youre hosted locally as it uses this as an additional ranking factor BUT compared to site speed and all the other ranking factors this one is small enough in significance to where you don't need to lose sleep over.

In this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXt23AXlJJU), Matt Cutts talks about this topic and says it is a factor like I already stated but this video is fairly old. Now there are many more items which can have a greater impact on your rankings than server location.

Think about this, all things being equal except for server location, if Google needs to decide whether to rank one of two sites #1, it'll choose the one with servers located in the country where the searcher is searching from.

Comment: For the record, where a site is hosted is not a ranking factor, however, excessively slow page speeds can effect SERP placement on a page by page basis. Case in point, an increasing number of .cn sites are hosted in the U.S. and in Europe. It is the delivery of the content and not where the content is located. However, having said that, locating content closest to your users can help with speed under normal circumstances. But there are also very fast network services out there where a U.S. site can be almost as fast in the U.K. or India.

Comment: I should say that a network neighborhood (in effect where a site is hosted- meaning a specific network) can be a trust ranking factor if the network is known for low quality sites or sites that behave badly. So when I said *where a site is hosted*, I am referring to geographic locale. Just to be clear.